# Unkown needok command Need 'PERSIST_TUN_ACTION' confirmation MSG:tunmethod

Tags: android, android-ndk, openvpn

I have an app that works on top of `ics-openvpn`

> - OpenSSL Library 1.0.1h + Ealier VPN library(PACKAGE_STRING "OpenVPN 2.3.2+dspatch4") = VPN
>     is connecting

***Note:***

I used NDK r8b builder

> - OpenSSL Library 1.0.1h + Latest VPN library(PACKAGE_STRING "OpenVPN 2.4-icsopenvpn") = VPN
>     is not connecting

it compiles but shows the following error on runtime and VPN is not connecting

> Unkown needok command Need 'PERSIST_TUN_ACTION' confirmation
>   MSG:tunmethod

***Note:***

I tried with NDk `r8b`,`r9` and `r10`

***FYI:***

Even the `ics-openvpn` also uses the the later combination I mentioned and the creator of the app also have tested the app successfully with r9 builder only.

***How I compiled using r9 ?***

1)I downloaded the NDK builder http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2

2)Went to `ADT->Preferences->Android->NDK` and gave the following path(where I unzipped) `/Users/username/Documents/Android/NDK/android-ndk-r9`

3)I right clicked on the project and added native support

that's it.This is how I did for r8b with earlier OpenVPN and latest Openssl and it worked and for the later combination also it compiles very good but but VPN is not connecting and when I see the logs I get the aforementioned question title as a message.

***No changes on OpenVPN server side is required:-***

I confirmed it by using the same OVPN file on Latest OpenVPN for Android and it established VPN connection

***I don't know where it goes wrong everything seems correct :***

```
 1. I have used the same library combination as latest ics-openvpn 
 2. I have used the same ndk builder as the author of the library 
 3. The Existing OVPN file works on latest OpenVPN for android
```

Any help is highly appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

That error is expected.

ics-openvpn consists of the OpenVPN part and the GUI part. Both parts need to fit together simply exchanging only one with an earlier or later version will break the app. There is no forward/backward compatibility implemented in either component.

P.S.: See also the answer I have given you on Google+.

Comment: I have updated my question to make more sense kindly go through it

Comment: My answer is still the same. Edited my answer for bit more details